# Alter http method in a rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

Could someone confirm it's not possible to change an http request method (from GET to POST for example) in a rewrite rule ?

A quote from some online doc would be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

`POST` can be redirected to `GET` with a `303 See Other` response per [RFC 7231, 6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4). Reading through the `3xx` response definitions and notes you can find out when a client may change the request method and how to prevent that.

All the other rewrites not involving URL redirection are internal and happens during the same request. Those won't invoke other requests at all which makes changing the method impossible.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's useful. To be more precise, I know there is something to do what I want in Nginx with "proxy_method" (Specifies the HTTP method to use in requests forwarded to the proxied server instead of the method from the client request) and I was looking for an equivalent feature in Apache.